# What should be the idle time of detection interval while requesting activity updates?

Tags: android, location

I am currently using the ActivityRecognitionClient API to get activity updates regularly. Now the detection interval I used to run it for only 3 seconds. I am getting the result, but along with that battery is draining faster also.

When I was going through android developer site for this, it says less detection interval will drain battery faster, but larger values will result in fewer activity detections while improving battery life. In that case if I put 30 sec or 20 sec time, then there are very few detection.

Website - [ActivityRecognitionClient API Details](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient)

> My question is here what should be the idle detection time interval we
> put so that we can get activity detection as well as our battery life
> also should not affect much.

Answer (score 0):

This is very opinionated but it truly depends on your use case. Figure out the average time for the use case and add some padding because you probably can't figure out a true standard deviation and that is your `interval`. Example if you are tracking vehicle movement, figure out the average drive time to work, in the US its 26 minutes according to google. Add like 3 minutes of padding and sample 3 times during that padding, if the user is stopped during all three samples you can safely say they have reached their destination, if not keep the interval going. What that results in is 6 samples in an hourish which is nothing to the battery.